# Why is my mail being marked as spam when send via Mvc.Mailer?

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-4, spam, nuget-package

I am using the Nuget Package Mvc.Mailer to send e-mail to my clients. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) and I'm encountering one really annoying thing. My sent e-mails are always sent to spam. Here's what my code looks like:

UserMailer:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Authenticatie(User user, string email)
    {
        ViewBag.User = user;
        ViewBag.Email = email;
        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "Your registration at Example";
            x.ViewName = "Registration";
            x.IsBodyHtml = true;
            x.From = "Name &lt;noreply@example.com&gt;";
            x.To.Add(email);
        });
    }
```

Registration.cshtml:

```
using Mvc.Mailer

<div>
    <p style="display: none">Stuff in my email</p>
<h1 style="background: #e68425; text-align: center; color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 10px;">
    A bunch of HTML
</h1>

<div style="background: #cf7721; text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
    <h3 style="margin: 0px;"><a href="@Url.Abs(Url.Action("ALink", "Administration", new { login = @ViewBag.User.Login, h = @ViewBag.User.Activation} ))">Activate account</a></h3>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Dear client,</p>

    <p>
        Thanks for bla bla bla... And more stuff.
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Login:</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.User.Login</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Activatiecode:</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.User.Activation</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Web.config:

```
<mailSettings>
  <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
  <smtp from="Example &lt;noreply@@example.com&gt;">
    <network enableSsl="false" host="mail.@example.com" port="25" userName="noreply@example.com" password="xxx" />
  </smtp>

</mailSettings>
```

**What we have tried**

1. Sending our e-mails via the standard way, with the SmtpClient. This mail didn't go to spam.
2. Setting x.From to a better name.
3. Different content types
4. `x.IsBodyHtml = true`
5. Sending an e-mail from our e-mail client (same address). This mail didn't go to spam.

**Questions**

1. Could our e-mail be filtered by excessive use of html?
2. Has anybody encountered this problem before, using this Nuget package?
3. How can I stop my e-mails from going to spam?
4. Above all: why are they going to spam?

Comment: Regarding your questions, have you tested multiple email clients? (Gmail/Outlook/Yahoo/etc). Spam is mainly filtered by the ISP/Content/Personal filters, so you'd have to look into making your email look less "Spammy". Can you try using the default UserMailer Welcome() template and seeing if that also goes to spam?

Comment: I don't think that's the reason, because when I send the exact same email with SmtpClient it doesn't go to spam. That must mean it's not the content, right? I'll try out some different clients!

Comment: Well it depends. SmtpClient might just be sending pure text in your tests vs. actually sending HTML. There are plenty of things that you can work on "fixing" within your HTML message, but first you'll need to check whether or not the template MVCMailer Welcome() message goes to spam or not. From there you can figure out that it can be an ISP/Untrusted Sender issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check all hyperlinks in template. It was just the word "email" in one of my Url.Action for becoming junk.